# How to trigger an action after the firebase-web result is recieved and manipulated

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

In my application I am requesting some results from Firebase and then I append it to my web page and then after I need to iterate the appended list items and I need to make some further functions but when I enter the code after the manipulation of Firebase result still it run before the Firebase result is appended.

How can I reiterate the list items after they're appended?

```
myfirebaseRef.child('subjects').orderByChild('course').equalTo('UG476BCS').on('child_added',function(subjectSnap){
    var subject=subjectSnap.val();

    $('#my-web-page .course-subjects').append('' +
        ' <li class="list-group-item ">' +
        '<div class="row padding-left-10">' +
        '<div class="col-md-8">' +
        '<span>' + subject.name + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-1">' +
        '<button class="btn btn-primary">pp</button>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</li>'
    )
});

$('#my-web-page .course-subjects li ').each(function(index){
    console.log(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're listening for the `child_added` event, which the [Firebase documentation describes](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types) as:

> `child_added` is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.

So your callback function will initially be invoked once for every child, and after that again every time a new child is added.

There are two possible scenarios:

1. You want to run your loop every time a child is added
2. You don't care about children that are added after you build the HTML

### Run after every child_added

If you want to run after any child is added (both the initial children and children added to the database later on), you move the loop into the callback:

```
var query = myfirebaseRef.child('subjects').orderByChild('course').equalTo('UG476BCS');
query.on('child_added',function(subjectSnap){
    var subject=subjectSnap.val();

    $('#my-web-page .course-subjects').append('' +
        ' <li class="list-group-item ">' +
        '<div class="row padding-left-10">' +
        '<div class="col-md-8">' +
        '<span>' + subject.name + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-1">' +
        '<button class="btn btn-primary">pp</button>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</li>'
    )
    // Now run over all children and log them
    $('#my-web-page .course-subjects li ').each(function(index){
        console.log(index);
    });
});
```

This will result in the logging loop being invoked many times, so you'll end up writing:

> 1

then

> 1
>
> 2

then

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

etc.

### Only build the HTML once

Alternatively, you can listen for a single `value` event and build the HTML based on that.

```
var query = myfirebaseRef.child('subjects').orderByChild('course').equalTo('UG476BCS')
.on('value',function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(subjectSnap){
    var subject=subjectSnap.val();

    $('#my-web-page .course-subjects').append('' +
        ' <li class="list-group-item ">' +
        '<div class="row padding-left-10">' +
        '<div class="col-md-8">' +
        '<span>' + subject.name + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-1">' +
        '<button class="btn btn-primary">pp</button>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</li>'
    )
  });
});

$('#my-web-page .course-subjects li ').each(function(index){
    console.log(index);
});
```

Now your callback will only be called *once* and it will be passed all the then current children in the database.

Comment: thank you, i can retrieve the data as you mentioned but what i want is to first append all the result to the web page and then i need to iterate the "li" items.

Comment: In your example the log will print 
0 because the items are not yet appended.
after printing only the result are appended , i need to change this as first append and then get the list of appended li.@Frank van Puffelen